# Select mysql rows where there exist 2 different values for same condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following dataset:

### Table 1

first_value | second_value

same | 1

same | 2

different1 |1

different2 |2

What I'd like to obtain from this table is **same** because 'same' exists for both "1" and "2". *different1* only exists for 1 and *different2* only exists for 2, so they are not chosen... is this possible? Thank you very much for your help...

Comment: Do you already know the numbers before?
What programming language are you using?

Comment: can you show a "real" example please ?? This is not very clear ...

Comment: @ceadreak read different1 as lorem and different2 as ipsum and it gets more clear.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard yes I do know the numbers, PHP (sorry for not saying this before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `group by` with `having` clause.

```
SELECT first_value
from Table1
where second_value in (1,2)
group by first_value
having count(*) =2
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on radar's answer and your comment that you're using php and already know the numbers:

```
$ids = array(1,2);//You probably already have an array holding your numbers

if(is_array($ids) && count($ids) >0) {

    $query = "SELECT col1 ".
             "FROM table1 ".
             "WHERE col2 IN (".join(",", $ids).") ".
             "GROUP BY col1 ".
             "HAVING COUNT(*) = ".count($ids);
}
```

If you're using parameterized queries it would of course look a little different.